# Limit max toastr messages to two

Tags: angular, toastr

I want to limit the maximum number of open toasts at a time.
I'm using ngx-toastr module and Angular5.
I've configured global settings like so :

```
ToastrModule.forRoot(
      { maxOpened: 2, 
        preventDuplicates: true,
        timeOut:2000,
        closeButton: true,
        progressBar:true,
        autoDismiss:true,
        newestOnTop:true}),
```

and even cleared the toasts before rendering them :

```
for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
  this.toastr.clear();
  this.toastr.info(''+i);
}
```

but still, many toast messages are showing at once.
[image]

Comment: Remove autoDismiss and try again.

Comment: please check [ask], this is not a [mcve]. First of all you should mention what toast lib you are using.

Comment: @LppEdd, I've tried that, it still shows multiple toasts

Comment: I would assume you don't actually show toasts like this? How does your code actually look like and are you facing issues there?  I tried by clicking buttons to open toasts, and even if I click fast, it only shows 2.

Comment: @AJT_82 no, but it is a socket connection so in some rare case there will be hundreds of messages at once. That for loop is a replica of how its happening.

Comment: ah, okay, I get it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a Stackblitz with a workaround to only allow two toasts at a time with a  setTimeout of 1 second.

```
for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
  ((ind)=>{ setTimeout(()=> this.toastr.info(''+i),1000*ind)})(i)
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phf1p6

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a simple jQuery selection:

```js
const MAX_TOASTS = 2;

toastr.subscribe(function(args) {
    if (args.state === 'visible')
    {
        var toasts = $("#toast-container > *:not([hidden])");
        if (toasts && toasts.length > MAX_TOASTS)
            toasts[0].hidden = true;
    }
});
```

The jQuery selection `$("#toast-container > *:not([hidden])")` selects all the children of the toast-container that do not have the attribute `hidden`.
Toastr, atleast when using the cdn version 2.1.4, adds the `hidden` attribute to every toast that is/will be hidden.

Setting a toast's hidden property to `true` hides it.